# separating gameloop input from simulation

Tags: c++, sdl

```
        // player control of box
        const Uint8* currentKeyStates = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

        if (currentKeyStates[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT]) {

        }
        if (currentKeyStates[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT]) {

        }
        if (currentKeyStates[SDL_SCANCODE_UP]) {

        }
        if (currentKeyStates[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN]) {

        }
```

I have read that the basic game loop is input, simulate, render. However in this example I am using keypresses to immediately move an object.

If I wanted to do that, I am not sure how to pass all possible key combinations into a function. If it was only one key at a time, then I would write:

```
void input_function(specific_key) {
}
```

Does it make sense separate the movement part from the input part in this case?

Comment: The movement part should be part of the simulation step. You *simulate* your player's movements, don't you?

Comment: The most straight-forward approach is to wire up corresponding flags on the objects in the input function, e.g. `if (esc_pressed) { game.shouldExit = true; } if (left_pressed) { player.shouldGoLeft = true; }`. The simulation will then use the flags, which, alone, will pretty much achieve the necessary separation level.

Alternatively, if you're in the early stages of writing the game, take a look at the Entity-Component-System approach, which should more or less dictate this kind of separation straight away.

Comment: @skink
Thanks for the advice, I will separate the code like this.